# Automatically update graph title with parameter

Tags: r

I am not very familiar with R. I was using R to make the poisson distribution plot for different lambda (from 1 to 10), and display the plot for each just as a comparison.

But I would like to add a title say: "lambda = 1" for plot 1, "lambda=2" for plot 2 ... etc on the graph automatically according to lambda. But I wasn't able to figure out how to update the title automatically. This is my code, I was able to output 10 different graph correctly , but not sure how to update or add the corresponding lambda to the title automatically. Could someone give me some hint.

Also is it possible to say have a font size of "small" for the plot 1 to 5, and then a font size of 6 to 10?

Thanks

```
the_data_frame<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=21))
lam<-seq(1,10,1)
lam
x<-seq(0,20,1)
x
for (i in 1:10){
the_data_frame[i]<-exp(-lam[i])*lam[i]**x/gamma(x+1)
}
the_data_frame<-cbind(the_data_frame, x)


par(mfrow=c(5,2))
for (i in 1:10){
plot(the_data_frame[[i]]~the_data_frame[[11]], the_data_frame)
}
```

Comment: what font size are you referring to? the title? the axis labels? the axis ticks?

Comment: sorry I should be more clear, I mean the title on the graph. Say for plot 1 to 5, I want the title to be font size of 12, and for plot 6 to 10, I want the title to be of font size of 8. I actually don't need to have the exact font size. I just want to know if there is a way to adjust the font size of the title automatically just like output the lambda on the title automatically. Sorry that I didn't make it clear originally.

Comment: @john_w You can set the general graph font size in points with a statement like  `par(ps=12)`; you can change the graph title font size multiplier with `cex.main=` in a `plot` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the problem. Using one loop, over the lamda values, you compute at each iteration the value of y using the poison formula then you plot it. I use `main` argument to add a title for each plot. Here I am using `bquote` to get a plotmath format of lambda value.

For example , for 4 values of lambda , you get:

```
x<-seq(0,20,1);lam = c(0.5,1,2,4)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
lapply(lam,function(lamd){
  y <- exp(-lamd)*lamd*x/gamma(x+1)
  plot(x,y,main=bquote(paste(lambda,'=',.(lamd))),type='l')

})
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, although there's a typo - `lambd ^ x` not `lambd * x`

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
for (i in 1:10){
    plot(the_data_frame[[i]]~the_data_frame[[11]], the_data_frame,
        main=paste("lambda=", i, sep=""))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
xval <- rep(0:20,10)
lambda <- rep(1:10,21)
yvtal <- exp(- lambda)*lambda**xval/gamma(xval+1)
the_new_data_frame <- data.frame(cbind(xval,lambda,yval))

plot1 <- ggplot(the_new_data_frame, aes(xval, yval)) + geom_line(aes(colour=factor(lambda)))
plot1
plot1 + facet_grid(~lambda)
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for an interactive window where you can input the text and update the figure title? If yes you may want to look for the tcltk package.

See 
http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/~wettenhall/RTclTkExamples/modalDialog.html